# Floating Action Button no Player - Animação de Play para Stop

Tags: android, animação

No meu app de rádio haverá um `FloatingActionButton` para dar o play.
O que eu gostaria muito era implementar neste `Button` a animação do ícone de play se transformando no de stop, mais ou menos como é mostrado [aqui](http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/delightful-details.html).

Eu procurei uma lib para isso mas não consegui encontrar, também porque não sei se isso é inerente à lib responsável pelo `FAB` ou é relativo apenas à imagem que é mostrada no `FAB`.

Alguém sabe como implementar esta funcionalidade?